# android-publisher verification testing

Tags: google-apis-explorer

Hi I am currently working on an app with an in-app-shop. Now I need to implemented Server Side Verification for Google In-app-purchases. We use https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-php-client for the verification. We already got the in app purchases and have tested the in app purchases with the test products (android.test.purchased). Is there a way to test the validation ? In the moment i get the following response when using a "android.test.purchased" for the following call

`$googleApiResult = $service->purchases_products->get($_ENV['PACKAGENAME'], $productId, $token);`

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": 400,
    "message": "Invalid Value",
    "errors": [
      {
            "message": "Invalid Value",
            "domain": "global",
            "reason": "invalid"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

In the docs it states that you need the productive data. The app has already an Alpha Track. On the alpha track in the Google Store the in app purchases are also approved but cannot get verified by the backend. Since the alpha track is a productive enviroment, we do not have the console or network logs to check whats the problem. What is the best practice here. Is there a way to debug verification ?

Answer (score 0):

In my case the problem is insufficent permission of my Google Client. I used the tokens which we got from the productive enviroment and used them in the local api.